# (python Selenium) AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'move_to_location'

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, linux-mint

To click on a specific location on the screen I use the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.set_window_size(500, 500)
driver.get('https://clickclickclick.click/')

actions = ActionChains(driver)

x_coord, y_coord = 250, 182 #coordinates of the button
actions.move_to_location(x_coord, y_coord).click().perform()
```

This piece of code clicks the prominently placed button on the website without raising an error if the code is ran on a Windows 10/11. If the code is ran on Linux Mint the following error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'move_to_location'
```

I did not succeed in finding the function in the documentation of selenium. Does anybody now if there is a way to make `move_to_location` also work on Linux Mint? Thank you for your time and effort in advance!

---

Edit: to illustrate this further `print(hasattr(actions, 'move_to_location'))` returns `True` on Windows 10/11 and `False` on Linux Mint

Comment: how is it even working on Windows when there's no such method like move_to_location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionsChains` class does not have a method called `move_to_location`.

However, `ActionsBuilder` class has this method. See the below code:

```
actions = ActionBuilder(driver)
actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(<x_coord>, <y_coord>).click()
actions.perform()
```

Update: Check the official documentation from below link for `ActionChains`, you will not find that method. I suggest recheck your code again to ensure `move_to_location` is being accessed by which class. It has to be `ActionBuilder`

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

Comment: Thank you very mutch!  I am wondering. Do you know why the method is accessible from ActionChains while it should not be (as far as I can understand)?

Comment: Further usefull documentation is available on [the selenium website](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/).

Comment: I still find it strange that the call is possible on Windows and not on Linux. The exact same code works on Windows and does not on Linux Mint. Is there someone who understands why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `move_by_offset` instead of `move_to_location`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.set_window_size(500, 500)
driver.get('https://clickclickclick.click/')

actions = ActionChains(driver)

x_coord, y_coord = 250, 182 #coordinates of the button
t = actions.move_by_offset(x_coord, y_coord).click().perform()
time.sleep(5)
```